# Zeitung vs. Beitung

Tags: noun, synonym, blackletter

What is the difference between *Zeitung* and *Beitung*? I was watching a documentary about WWI and a Viennese newspaper used *Beitung*. Is this still in usage? Are the  words interchangeable. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of questioned newspaper]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not Beitung, it's actually Zeitung. In the blackletter typeface used for the headline the Z looks much like a B.

There are "modern" blackletter typefaces which use a Z shaped like in antiqua typefaces, but the shape one can see in the newspaper is actually the authentic one. See for example the Fraktur letters shown here: [Mathematical blackletters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter#Unicode)

Generally the blackletter Z looks like a 3, but here the added vertical lines make it look like a B.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it could be something as simple. Best. Sloan,.

Answer (score -3):

Even as a native speaker I had to look up "Beitung". It is not in use and wasn't probably since even before WWI.
While "Zeitung" just means newspaper or in certain contexts the editorial staff of of a newspaper, the "Beitung" meant something like to wait for something or to give someone some sort of respite.
So the one has nothing to with the other.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I went back and added a screenshot for context which I should have done initially. Thanks again for your assistance. It's very much appreciated. SX

Answer (score -3):

They aren't related.

There is a really old verb *beiten* which means *to bide*. It's not even present in Luther's bible translation. That's how old it is. It survived in some upper German dialects, that's maybe how it got into that documentation.

That *Beitung* is a noun made from that verb: *biding.* It is not a common noun either.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I went back and added a screenshot for context which I should have done initially. Thanks again for your assistance. It's very much appreciated. SX.

Comment: That is a German Blackletter (Fraktur) Z in your photo. It looks like a 3 usually, and some fonts add a vertical bar to tell it apart from a 3. The Fraktur B looks much different.